# Is there a way to toggle hiding/showing several sheets using VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

I've got an excel workbook with over 50 tabs, but only some of these tabs are relevant for specific projects.

I've created a 'Scoping' tab whereby I have all the tab names in one column and then a hide/show column depending on whether I want to hide or not hide that tab, which looks a bit like this;
[Scoping tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaWwz.png)

Is there a VBA macro that I can make that will automatically run down this list and hide or not hide depending on the value in the second column? Ideally without having to enter the tab names in to the code (i.e it picks it up automatically from the scoping tab)?

I can do this for a select tab i.e Worksheets("Sheet1").visible = False but unsure how to loop this without having to change "Sheet1" every time?

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple to pull off with VBA. You can do something like the following:

```
Sub hideThemTabs()
    Dim tabCell as Range
    
    'Loop through the range of cells holding your 
    '  tab names:
    'Change the range here to match your scoping sheet
    '  only the column in which the tab names are listed
    '  are needed. We will use `offset()` to find 
    '  whether we should show or hide the sheet. 
    For Each tabCell in Sheets("Scoping").Range("A2:A50") 
        
        'Show or hide the tab based on if the cell 
        '   in the column next to the tab name says 
        '   "Show" or not. 
        Sheets(tabCell.Value).Visible = (tabCell.Offset(0,1).value = "Show")

    Next tabCell           

End Sub
```